# What is a Scary Number™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Scary Number™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

> | Scary Numbers™ |
> | --- |
> | -1555487920 |
> | -739891358 |
> | -142598657 |
> | -70140871 |
> | -1671766 |
> | 4450548 |
> | 17452800 |
> | 84508223 |
> | 272393477 |
> | 598734170 |
> | 730747057 |
> | 798300167 |
> | 1000212371 |
> | 1506920732 |

"What about Non-Scary Numbers™?" I hear you ask.

Fortunately, the vast majority of numbers are Non-Scary Numbers™. However, I'm more than willing to check for you if your number is Scary or not.

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Scary Numbers

-1555487920 
-739891358  
-142598657  
-70140871   
-1671766    
4450548      
17452800     
84508223     
272393477    
598734170    
730747057    
798300167    
1000212371   
1506920732
```

Comment: One big reason that usually Non-X examples are provided is to prevent the puzzle from devolving into an [off-topic semi-interactive guessing game](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6356/69582). Can this puzzle be solved in its current state?

Comment: @bobble Yes, it can be solved. Explaining why actually *kind of* acts as a hint, so I won't do that right now. For now, I would say that knowing what some Non-Scary Numbers are is almost completely useless to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scary number is

> A timestamp of a date where a terrorist attacks happened

For example (more to come):

-1555487920

> September 16, 1920 : [Wall street bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_Street_bombing)

-739891358

> July 22, 1946 : [King David Hotel bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_David_Hotel_bombing)

-142598657

> June 25, 1965 : [Saigon bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1965_Saigon_bombing)

-70140871

> October 12, 1967 : [Cyprus Airways Flight 284 bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus_Airways_Flight_284)

-1671766

> December 12, 1969 : [Piazza Fontana bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piazza_Fontana_bombing)

4450548

> February 21, 1970 : [Swissair Flight 330 bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swissair_Flight_330)

17452800

> July 22, 1970 : [Olympic Airways Flight 255 hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/July_1970#July_22,_1970_(Wednesday))

84508223

> September 5, 1972 : [Munich_massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_massacre)

272393477

> August 19, 1978 : [Cinema Rex fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_Rex_fire)

598734170

> December 21, 1988 : [Pan Am Flight 103 bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_103)

730747057

> February 26, 1993: [1993 World Trade Center bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_World_Trade_Center_bombing)

798300167

> April 19, 1995 : [Oklahoma City bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma_City_bombing)

1000212371

> September 11, 2001 : [September 11 attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks)

1506920732

> October 1, 2017 (though the timestamp is on the 2nd): [2017 Las Vegas shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Las_Vegas_shooting)

As another exemple, I find the number 1447391132 quite scary too.

Comment: That is correct! The reason why the 2017 Las Vegas shooting is on the 2nd is because I converted the time to UTC.